# Render Component Fixed Number of Times (Asynchronously)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to render the same component a fixed number of times(entered by the user) one after the other (Asynchronously). For this, I have used the below function passing as props approach where a while loop is used to make the code run asynchronously and could progress only after the state variable *componentRendered* becomes *true*, but it's not working. Could someone help to figure this out. Thanks in advance.

**HomeScreen.js**

```
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';
import Stepper from '../components/Stepper';

class HomeScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      componentRendered: false,
    };
  }

  setComponentRender = () => {
    this.setState({componentRendered: true});
  };

  render() {
    var stepperElement = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
      stepperElement.push(
        <Stepper setComponentRender={this.setComponentRender} />,
      );
      while (this.state.componentRendered === false) {}
      this.setState({componentRendered: false});
    }
    return <View>{stepperElement}</View>;
  }
}

export default HomeScreen;
```

**Stepper.js**

```
import {View, TextInput, Text, Alert} from 'react-native';
import {ProgressSteps, ProgressStep} from 'react-native-progress-steps';

class Stepper extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: '',
    };
  }

  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null,
  };

  defaultScrollViewProps = {
    keyboardShouldPersistTaps: 'handled',
    contentContainerStyle: {
      flex: 1,
      justifyContent: 'center',
    },
  };

  onNextStep = () => {
    console.log('called next step');
  };

  onPaymentStepComplete = () => {
    Alert.alert(
      'Payment completed!',
      'Your Payment is Successful',
      [
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'),
          style: 'cancel',
        },
        {text: 'OK', onPress: () => console.log('OK Pressed')},
      ],
      {cancelable: false},
    );
  };

  onPrevStep = () => {
    console.log('called previous step');
  };

  onSubmitSteps = () => {
    console.log('called on submit step.');
    this.props.setComponentRender();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, marginTop: 50}}>
        <ProgressSteps>
          <ProgressStep
            label="Payment"
            onNext={this.onPaymentStepComplete}
            onPrevious={this.onPrevStep}
            scrollViewProps={this.defaultScrollViewProps}>
            <View style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
              <Text>Payment step content</Text>
            </View>
          </ProgressStep>
          <ProgressStep
            label="Confirm Order"
            onPrevious={this.onPrevStep}
            onSubmit={this.onSubmitSteps}
            scrollViewProps={this.defaultScrollViewProps}>
            <View style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
              <Text>Confirm order step content</Text>
            </View>
          </ProgressStep>
        </ProgressSteps>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default Stepper;
```

Comment: Never this: `while (this.state.componentRendered === false) {}`. Why aren't you using a timer or animation library or...? And you really don't want to call `setState` in `render`, which can lead to infinite renders and shenanigans.

Comment: Yeah I agree with not keeping setState in render method
But I can't use timers as I'm using **Stepper** which can be found here (https://github.com/colbymillerdev/react-native-progress-steps). And I need to execute this making my for loop wait until _Stepper component_ is rendered completely.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What specifically do you mean by "rendered completely"?

Comment: By saying **rendered completely** I want to say that in the *Stepper.js* when the _onSubmitSteps_ callback gets executed than on the next loop iteration should run in the _for loop_ of *HomeScreen.js*.

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "exexuted"? Is there an animation you're trying to wait for? Are you trying to have them appear one after the other? If the component has no callback for when it's "complete" you're at the whim of React unless you take control.

Comment: Actually I want to combine this with stepper (https://github.com/colbymillerdev/react-native-progress-steps) where each time user will be allowed to crop different parts of the same image. So in my execution flow, I want to the Stepper to get completed entirely and then the next iteration starts. So in short in each iteration, the stepper should be finished completely and then the next iteration should go around.